# How do I restart the scene when no collision for 5secs (BGE)

Tags: game-engine

Im working in the game engine, I want to restart my game asap my character had no collision for more than 5 secs.
Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever your character measures a collision, you send a message "reset timer".

Have one object with a timer property (which measures in seconds).

- When the property exceeds 5.0 you restart the scene (property sensor greater than mode).
- When a message with subject "reset timer" is received set the property back to -5 (property actuator Assign mode)

[Edit]
just in case the character detects constant collision, I suggest to enable [True Level Triggering] at the collision sensor. This way the message gets constantly send and the timer gets constantly reset.

Comment: I tried, when the game restarts the timer disappears (saw this in debug mode)
(screen) : http://bit.ly/2jwZH1o

Comment: I would not restart the game as is. Because this is really like ending and starting the game (loosing any previous information). I would restart the scene. I can't tell about "the timer disappears" this sounds strange. I never saw such behavior. I noticed with 2.78 in embedded mode the game quits, rather restarted.

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice. Should've read your message better. It works well !!